# Selector.xpath().get() returns all elements after xpath target

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, selector

Here is my html code that I'm pulling from

```
from scrapy import Selector
import requests
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<html>
<body>
​
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
​
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
​
</body>
</html>
'''
```

Then I'm using scrapy selector

```
sel = Selector( text = html )
```

I then use xpath to select an element but it also returns everything after the targeted element

```
in:
sel.xpath('/html/body/h1').get()
out:
'<h1>My First Heading</h1>\n\n<p>My first paragraph.</p>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

I'm expecting it to return:

```
'<h1>My First Heading</h1>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you are using is correct. Your expression returns the expected result on my end. Try the alternative below.

```py
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(text=html)
>>> sel.xpath("//h1").get()
'<h1>My First Heading</h1>'
```

Comment: It's still returning everything after. I edited my post to show the packages I imported. Maybe that is affecting it?

Comment: The `Selector` object is imported from `scrapy.selector` module. I have edited the answer to show you how I import it. What version of `scrapy` are you using?

Comment: I'm using version Scrapy 2.5.1. I tried using your import and no change. I may try running this on a different python environment than Jupyter.